# node is not returning the correct answer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code in a file called index.js

```
function Answer(value) {
  this._val = value;
}

Answer.prototype.get = function get() {
  return this._value;
}

var lifeAnswer = new Answer(42);
console.log(lifeAnswer.get());

var piAnswer = new Answer(3.14159);
console.log(piAnswer.get());
```

But when I run it using node as follows, I get the following output node index.js :

```
undefined
undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `return this._val;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo;

```
Answer.prototype.get = function get() {
   return this._value; // this line should be: return this._val;
}
```